# Is it possible to authenticate using more than two variable in django?

Tags: django

I have created a custom user model in django? there are many fields including `email, password and username`.
Now I want to authenticate using `username,password and email` while login. How should I do that?

Comment: do you need user to enter three inputs while logging in ?

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge yes!

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a custom authentication backend.

```
from django.db.models import Q

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

user = get_user_model()

class UsernameAndEmailBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
       email = kwargs.get('email')
       if email is None or username is None:
            return None
       try:
            user = MyUser.objects.get(username=username, email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
       except MyUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Then, in your settings.py set AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS to your authentication backend:

```
 AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('path.to.UsernameAndEmailBackend,)\
```